# why can't i move directly from one scene to another scene from another group of scenes in react native _ react-native-router-flux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

i'm using:
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
"react-native": "0.59.5",

i want to go to another scene which is located in another group of scenes. as i remember it was possible in RNRF v3 but since i updated the library it's not working. it was like calling Actions.login() from homePage.

here is what my rout looks like:
https://pasteboard.co/IjYo6wo.png

right now i have to reset the path but i need the last page to stored in stack which is not possible

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={this.renderLoading()}>
        <Root>
            <Router backAndroidHandler={this.onBackPress}>
                <Scene hideNavBar>
                    <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
                        <Drawer contentComponent={DrawerLayout} key="drawer" drawerPosition="right">
                            <Lightbox>
                                <Scene hideNavBar>
                                    <Scene key="homePage" component={HomePage} initial back='true' />
                                    <Scene key="departments" component={Departments} back />
                                </Scene>
                                <Scene key="LightBox" component={CityLightBox} />
                            </Lightbox>

                        </Drawer>
                    </Scene>

                    <Scene key="auth" hideNavBar>
                        <Scene key="login" component={Login} initial />
                        <Scene key="signUp" component={SignUp} />
                    </Scene>

                    <Scene key="splash" hideNavBar component={Splash} initial />
                </Scene>

            </Router>
        </Root>
    </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

i want to move from homePage to login directly and with back button it will pop up the homePage again.
it's possible if homePage and login are siblings in same scene group.

Comment: I have same issue. I can not navigate any screen without {type:"reset"} and this is my question about this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733215/react-native-router-flux-freezing-without-typereset

Answer (score 0):

it's not working the same way as it used to. i used **Actions.push('rootscene')**. still **can not** move to specific scene directly but it keeps the last scene in stack.