# React Native Router Flux Freezing Without {type:reset}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using *React Native Router Flux* on my mobile app for routing.

Page structure is like;

**Login.js**
 Get user password and username validation and store user-token in AsyncStorage
 If app has user-token redirect user to MainPage.js

( redirection in `ComponentWillMount()` method )

**MainPage.js**
 Make API call to my back-end server for listing some data

**DetailPage.js**
 Make API call to my back-end server for some detailed data.

--

My Router structure;

```
<Roter>
    <Scene key="root">
        <Scene initial component={Login} key="login" />
        <Scene component={MainPage} key="mainpage" />
        <Scene component={DetailPage} key="detailpage" />
    </Scene>
</Router>
```

--

Problem is;

When I want to navigate from **MainPage** to **DetailPage**, I cannot use `Actions.detailpage()` without `Actions.detailpage({type:"reset"})`

If I try to use only `Actions.detailpage()` app is freezing on MainPage. But I console.log("this is detail page") I can see the output. Actually I can navigate with `Actions.detailpage()` but my DetailPage can not load to screen.

I have network calls. Does not navigation stack handle this heavy process?

If i use `Actions.detailpage({type:"reset"})` , navigation history is missing. So I can not use back buttons on top navbar.

What I'm missing here?

> Actions reset property: Clears the routing stack and pushes the scene
>   into the first index. No transition will occur.

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md#actions

---

Edit:

When I delete all my routing config and add two empty scene like PageA.js and PageB.js, still it is freezing when I try to jump from PageA to PageB

```
<Roter>
        <Scene key="root>
            <Scene initial component={PageA} key="page_a" />
            <Scene component={PageB} key="page_b" />
        </Scene>
    </Router>
```

Still I get same error. Something on my app blocking page rendering and Scene loading. How I inspect this issue?

Also my dependencies are;

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.4.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-facebook-account-kit": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-iap": "^2.5.5",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.5.0"
  },
```

Comment: can you try `Actions.reset("detailpage")`? also, there is a typo with your `<Router>` tag and a missing double quote for `key` prop. have them fixed before trying again.

Answer (score 0):

have you used **Actions.push('scene key')**?
i'm having trouble moving to specific scene directly but this one might helps you.
i thinking about using react navigation